# Is the range of the function f ( x ) = | x | : R → R the same as the target?

Tags: functions

Is the range of the function  f ( x ) = | x | : R → R  the same as the target?

I need help determining that answer to this and a brief explanation of why

I also have a similar question

Is the range of the function  t o U p p e r ( a ) : A → A  the same as the target?

I think the Target is referring to all real numbers R.

Comment: Sometimes notations like range and target are ambiguous. Thus, would you like to post your definition?

Comment: What do you mean by target?

Comment: The set of all real numbers I suppose. I just started learning functions yesterday. I think target is all possible real numbers  R

Comment: @JeremyJackson I would interepete is this way as well.

Comment: What is meant by "A" ?

Comment: I believe toUpper sets all letters to capital letters. So I assume A is the set of all capital letters. I could be wrong though

Comment: In this case, target and range would be the same. The function is surjective because for every y in $A$ there is an $x$ with "$upper(x)=y$". In fact, "upper" would be the idendity.

Answer (score 1):

The target is just the set $\mathbb R$, the set to which the values are mapped by the funtion.

The domain is the set of possible values of the function and this is the set of non-negative-real numbers in this case.

So, they are not the same.

Comment: Does this go for both questions? Also, can you explain a little, so I'll know how to figure it out on my own

Comment: To be more concrete, the range is the set of all real numbers $y$, such that there is an $x$ with $f(x)=y$, whereas the target is a set in which all values $f(x)$ lie.